# Refactoring code that evaluate only specific values in a Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, loops, hash, key-value

I have a long hash, consisting of some hashes within hashes.  Right now I just need to evaluate only a select few of the hash's values.

```
if params[:my_hash]["start_date(1i)"].empty? || params[:my_hash]["start_date(2i)"].empty? || params[:my_hash]["start_date(3i)"].empty? || params[:my_hash]["start_date(4i)"].empty?
    redirect_to :back
    flash[:error] = "Must include a start date."
    return
end
```

It works fine, but I need to dry it up. I've been trying to find a way to just loop over *these specific keys/values* instead of calling each hash key by name.  I know how I would do this if it were an array (just look at the indexes), but I'm having a tough time formulating something that would work for a hash.